# How do Mount Moriah and Zion compare with each other in 2 Chronicles?

Tags: 2-chronicles, geography

**2 Chronicles 3:1** (ESV)

> Then Solomon began to build the house of the LORD in Jerusalem on Mount Moriah, where the LORD had appeared to David his father, at the place appointed, on the threshing floor of Oman the Jebusite.

**2 Chronicles 5:2** (ESV)

> Then Solomon assembled the elders of Israel and all the leaders of the fathers' houses of the people of Israel, in Jerusalem, to bring up the ark of the covenant of the LORD out of the city of David, which is Zion.

In 2 Chronicles how does Mount Moriah compare with Zion: A. Geographically?
B. Symbolically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Moriah" is uncomplicated, "Zion" is a lot messier because its meaning changed over time.

**Moriah מוֹרִיָּה**

The name, "Moriah" occurs only twice in the OT -

- Gen 22:2 - “Take your son,” God said, “your only son Isaac, whom you love, and go to the land of **Moriah**. Offer him there as a burnt offering on one of the mountains, which I will show you.”
- 2 Chron 3:1 - Then Solomon began to build the house of the LORD in Jerusalem on Mount **Moriah**, where the LORD had appeared to his father David. This was the place that David had prepared on the threshing floor of Ornan the Jebusite.  (Compare 2 Sam 24:18.)

Thus, Solomon's temple appears to have been was built on the hill where Abraham attempted to offer Isaac as a sacrifice but was stopped by the Angel of the LORD.  This hill has now disappeared beneath the debris and huge foundations required for both Herod's temple and later the Mohammedan precinct.

**Zion צִיּוֹן (Tsiyyon)**

Originally, "Zion" designated the stronghold of the city of the Jebusites (2 Sam 5:7) which David captured and renamed as the "City of David" (1 Kings 8:1, 1 Chron 11:5, 2 Chron 5:2, etc).  Mt Zion is located on the narrow ridge between the valley of Kidron and the valley of Tyropoeon, about 600 m (2000 ft.) south of Mt Moriah.

Later, the Name "Zion" simply indicated the entire city of Jerusalem, 2 Kings 19:21, 31, Ps 9:11, 14, etc.

In still later times, "Zion" designated the temple mount as well, Isa 2:3, 8:18, etc.  Then "Zion" came to designate the entire city and its inhabitants, Ps 48:11, 12, Isa 1:8, 10:32, Joel 2:23, Zech 9:13, etc.

In NT times, "Sion" was used to describe the entire city of Jerusalem, both literally (Matt 21:5, John 12;15) and metaphorically (Rom 11:26) and spiritually, Heb 12:22, 1 Peter 2:6, Rom 9:33, Rev 14:1, etc.